# Im trying to learn javascript on Code Academy could someone explain the purpose of "return 1;" at the end of this function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function dogCare()
{
    alert("walk 9am: twice around the block");
    alert("Feed at 4pm: Meat & Water");
    alert("walk at 10pm: once around the block");
    return 1;
}
```

Why is there a `return 1;` at the end of the function and what is its purpose.

Comment: Would you show the caller? In this function, return 1; is not required.

Comment: To be fair I read where a return like that can help keep the page from skipping back to the top but I have no idea if that is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Where you call that function from it returns 1 to the caller.

e.g.

```
var x = dogCare();
console.log('DogCare returned ' + x);
```

In Firefox run with Firebug to view the console output.

PS: I think you should feed the dog at least twice a day!

Comment: `s/Firefox/any modern browser/`

Comment: @MattBall - Agreed - They all give the debuggers different names though. Also IE does not have console defined unless you are running developers tools (is that the right name)

Comment: I'd say three times per day :P

Answer (score 0):

It returns the value `1` to whatever piece of code called that function. Accordingly:

```
var foo = dogCare();
// foo is 1
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score -1):

The number "1" is equivalent to the boolean value "true". I can only assume that there is a check somewhere for a "successful" return from the function.

Comment: only ==, not === though.